# Find a linear transformation $M:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ where $\mathrm{nullity}(M)=1$ and $\mathrm{nullity}(M^2)=2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear transformation $M:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ where $\mathrm{nullity}(M)=1$ and $\mathrm{nullity}(M^2)=2$

So the way I approached it seemed elementary. But I started out with something that has a $\mathrm{nullity}(M) = 1$. So like:

$$ M= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I know this has a $\mathrm{nullity}(M)=1$ but the tricky part is squaring it. My approach was to use this as a template and just simply add stuff to it to make it work. I have an idea that you would involve complex numbers, such as $i$. But after countless combinations of ways to write my matrix, I can't seem to get the $\mathrm{nullity}(M^2) = 2$. My question is, what's the best way to approach this problem? I feel like this isn't a hard problem and I am probably missing something. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Think upper triangular (in fact, non-diagonalisable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose I have three balls, in positions $1$, $2$, and $3$. Here is an operation that when done once throws away one ball, and when done twice throws away two balls:

> Throw out the ball in position $1$. Move the remaining balls down one.

(Consider the balls as coordinates in an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Do you see what matrix this describes?)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is the standard matrix for the linear transformation $M$. Then $A$ has columns $M(e_1)$, $M(e_2)$, $M(e_3)$ where $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

As $\operatorname{Nullity}(M) = 1$, we have $\dim\ker(M) = 1$. So let $M(e_1) = 0$, but $M(e_2), M(e_3) \neq 0$.

As $\operatorname{Nullity}(M^2)= 2$, we have $\dim\ker(M^2) = 2$. Note that $M^2(e_1) = 0$; suppose $M^2(e_2) = 0$ but $M^2(e_3) \neq 0$. As $M^2(e_2) = 0$ and $M(e_2) \neq 0$, $M(e_2) \in \ker M = \langle e_1\rangle$; let $M(e_2) = e_1$.

So we have $M(e_1) = 0$, $M(e_2) = e_1$, and set $M(e_3) = e_3$. The standard matrix of this linear transformation is

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

and the standard matrix of $M^2$ is

$$A^2 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right].$$